# Permission denied when trying to read temporary file created in bash

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I am trying to write a script which takes as arguments one or more files and transposes the upper case letters to lower case letters. The contents of the original file is replaced with the lower case only content.

A file given in arguments has to exist, it has to be a normal file, it must be allowed in read/write and it cannot be allowed in execution nor be empty.

```
# We assume the current file is valid.
declare valide="true"

if (("$#" < 1)) ; then
   # Error, you must enter at least one parameter.
   echo -e "Erreur. Vous devez entrer au moins un parametre."
fi

for param in "$@" ; do

   if [ ! -e $param ] ; then
      $valide="false"
   elif [ ! -f $param ] ; then
      $valide="false"
   elif [ ! -r $param ] ; then
      $valide="false"
   elif [ ! -w $param ] ; then
      $valide="false"
   elif [ -x $param ] ; then
      $valide="false"
   elif [ -s $param ] ; then
      $valide="false"
   fi

   if [ $valide=="true" ] ; then
      # Create temporary file.

      ficTemp=$(/usr/bin/mktemp)

      $(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < $param > $ficTemp)
      $($ficTemp > $param)
   else
      # Error, the file $param is invalid for this script.

      echo -e "Erreur. Le fichier $param est invalide pour ce script."
   fi

done
```

My problem is that when I execute the script in a normal shell (not root) I get the following error:

```
line 45: /tmp/tmp.xxx: Permission denied
```

Here is the result of a ls -ld /tmp :

```
drwxrwxrwt. 12 root root 380 May 14 18:35 /tmp
```

Comment: Then forget about the whole script and concentrate on that permission error.  Can that user create other files in /tmp?

Comment: It might also be useful to see the output of `sestatus`.

Comment: Yes, I can do `touch /tmp/file` and the file is created no problem. sestatus returns that SE Linux is enabled. Do you need more info ? @JuliePelletier

Comment: AFH has the correct answer to your problem, but, additionally: (1) You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$param"`, `"$ficTemp"`, and, to be really safe, `"$valide"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  Strictly speaking, you don’t *need* to quote simple constant strings like `"true"` and `"false"`, although, of course, it doesn’t hurt.  And ***do*** keep `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` in quotes — `[` is a special character, and it needs to be quoted.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) You don’t need to test `-e` *and* `-f` unless you want to issue different error messages — if the `-f` test succeeds, you know the file exists, and so the `-e` test is redundant.  (3) Don’t use `echo -e` unless you have a reason to — it will cause trouble if a filename contains backslash(s).  (4) As a special case, you can abbreviate `for param in "$@"; do` to `for param do`.  (5) In addition to AFD’s answer: you don’t need (and ***should not have***) `$(` and `)` around the `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < "$param" > "$ficTemp"` command.

Comment: Thank you for taking some time out of your Saturday evening to answer my question :P I made the modifications you suggested, and something else was not working : `if [ $valide=="true" ] ; then` had to be changed to `if [ $valide == "true" ] ; then`. Good night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which line 45 is, but the line `$($ficTemp > $param)` is wrong and would probably give this error: it tries to execute the temporary file as a script and write its output to `$param`, then execute the returned string.

There are two obvious things wrong:-

1. Unless you have an unusual `umask` you have not made the temporary file executable, hence the error.
2. The script's output is redirected, so there will never be anything returned, and the `$()` serves no purpose.

What are you trying to do? If you want to copy the temporary file back over the original, then any of the following will do it:-

```
cat $ficTemp > "$param"
cp $ficTemp "$param"
mv $ficTemp "$param"
```

The last of these is more efficient, because it does not need to access the data and it removes the temporary file at the same time, but the original owner and access permissions are replaced (thanks to G-Man for pointing this out).

Whatever you do, you should use `"$param"`, to allow for embedded spaces in the file name or path.

Comment: Great answer, I understand my mistake. Line 45 is the line you pointed out. Thank you so much!

Comment: `cat "$ficTemp" > "$param"` or `cp "$ficTemp" "$param"` would be good ways to preserve the identity and attributes of the source file.

Comment: @G-Man - Thanks for the comment: I have updated my answer to include a qualification about the use of `mv`.